# MoSKito Java Monitoring Tool

Tags: java, tomcat, cluster-computing, performance

I'm looking for free open source framework/tool for Java applications and Tomcat cluster monitoring.

The are pretty much tools and frameworks out there (Zabbix, Nagious) but most has GPL license, what makes them impossible for use withing commercial products. Others, has limited charts (JavaMelody) and does not support, or very weak support, for cluster data aggregation.

Recently, I came across [MoSKito](http://www.moskito.org/) which looks very promising and has MIT license but I can't really find any reviews on that and not sure how active is that project.

So, would appreciate to get any feedbacks on MoSKito ?

Thanks,
Pavel

Comment: I'd like to point-out that the GPL doesn't prevent you from using Zabbix or Nagios to monitor your own proprietary applications. The rumors of the GPL's viral nature are greatly exaggerated.

Comment: FYI, questions looking for libraries belong on the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange sister site rather than there on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well I am a little bit biased, because I am also a commiter in the MoSKito project, but I'll answer nevertheless ;-)
There were like 9 releases (2 major) of the project alone this year, which I think is an indicator that the project is active.
Personally I use it in 3 projects on daily base. The biggest installation I am aware of consists of over 100 JVMs running on 18 machines.

The source code is on github:

```
https://github.com/anotheria/moskito  
https://github.com/anotheria/moskito-control  
https://github.com/anotheria/moskito-central  
https://github.com/anotheria/moskito-control-agent
```

If you have any further questions feel free to PM me ;-)

regards
Leon

Answer (score 2):

We have been using MoSKito for more than three years to monitor an onlive platform with about 20 machines and around 100 JVMs running on them, which Leon mentioned above.

Our experience with MoSKito was good. It is very robust. Has a relatively low performance impact, as far as I can tell. Attaching monitoring points can be done quite easily with Annotations. And it does what it shows on the Web-Site and does that well. The developers are always open for suggestions and discussions. The projects is very active.

We did not yet use the relatively new MoSKito central, which can aggregate and store performance data, so I can not say anything about that.

MoSKito does not record all the performance data for each request. It only records averages. On the other hand you can track single requests/sessions by marking them with a request parameter, which can be very handy to analyse performance problems. Doing so shows you a full "stacktrace" of the request with all the performance data and parameters recorded at each MoSKito monitoring point.

I can't compare MoSKito to other tools, since MoSKito is the only tool I used extensively, but I was happy with it.